# LINQ to SQL: InsertOnSubmit() vs Add()

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, datacontext

What is the best way to insert new child records: to use `Add()` or `InsertOnSubmit()` ?
Is there any difference between those to approaches ?

`InsertOnSubmit()` example:

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   Parent p = db.Parents.Where(q => q.ID == SomeID).SingleOrDefault();
   Child c = new Child();
   c.ForeignKeyID = p.ID;
   db.InsertOnSubmit(c);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

`Add()` example:

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   Parent p = db.Parents.Where(q => q.ID == SomeID).SingleOrDefault();
   Child c = new Child();
   p.Add(c);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: well its up to you - whats more clear to you and your code?

Comment: How is `Parent.Add` defined?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, it looks like OP made a typo, and is talking about [EntityCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351713%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already have the parent ID, it would be more efficient to do this:

```
using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
   Child c = new Child();
   c.ForeignKeyID = SomeID;
   db.InsertOnSubmit(c);
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

This way you're not retrieving the parent first and relying on object tracking to find the new item.